# Django - how to determine if model class is abstract

Tags: django, django-models

If a django model is made abstract, like below, is there a way to inspect the class to determine that it is abstract?

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
  class Meta:
    abstract = True
```

I would expect that I could examine MyModel.Meta.abstract, but according to Django docs:

> Django does make one adjustment to the Meta class of an abstract base class: before installing the Meta attribute, **it sets abstract=False**. This means that children of abstract base classes don't automatically become abstract classes themselves.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: What's wrong with reading the source?  It's always available.

Comment: The abstract from docs is related to derived class' Meta, not base's.

Comment: @S.Lott - Indeed, I RTFM but failed to RTFS. To be fair, many of the questions on S.O. could probably be self-answered by reading the source.

@Dmitry - I'm a bit confused by your comment. From django/db/basy.py, it appears that all of the attributes in the Meta class are transferred to a new class referenced as _meta. It's this class that holds the original abstract value set in models' Meta classes.

Regardless, @sheats answered my question (Thanks again).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can instantiate MyModel and then check ._meta.abstract.

So in code:

```
m = MyModel()
print m._meta.abstract
```

Comment: I didn't spot that in dir(MyModel), but it's there. Thanks very much.

Comment: If you haven't looked into iPython I would strongly suggest it.  It is very useful for playing around and finding out these things since it offers auto-completion.  That's how I found this one =)

Comment: Is it normal to access to a protected member from outside in Python?

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to point out that you don't need to instantiate a model to check if it's abstract - Django models inherit an actual metaclass that adds _meta on class instantiation.

So, similarly to @sheats's code, try

```
from django.db.models import Model
class MyModel(Model):
  pass
print MyModel._meta.abstract
```

Or, for a positive example

```
from django.db.models import Model
class MyModel(Model):
  class Meta(object):
    abstract = True
print MyModel._meta.abstract
```

Of course, this also works for built-in models and anything inheriting from Django's Model.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
print User._meta.abstract
```